# Does Blender has anything like Adobe After Effects' aerender command-line interface application?

Tags: video

Does Blender has anything like Adobe After Effects' aerender command-line interface application?

In long run, I want to automate creating video based on template using images and text.

**More details**

I am new to this but I will try my best to explain, I saw someone using aerender and some template with extension "aep" to create a video using images and text.

Now I am not sure if Blender supports such templates (I am not entirely sure what templates do but I think they add effects)

I did some research and I found out blender has cli which could be used for rendering as well, but I still don't know how to create a template and how it all collerate

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/workflows/command_line.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you expand upon your question a little bit? What exactly does the aerender application do? How would this look in Blender?

Comment: Update question with more info